# expect error handling - spawn id not open

Tags: linux, ssh, error-handling, expect

I'm writing an expect script which can log out in hundreds of routers and change their config.

My problem is, there is a bug on the routers firmware which causes them to close the connection after the password is send.
If I log in again, it works perfectly (so only the first log in after reboot causes the exception).
When the connection is closed the expect script is terminated.

I would like if i could gracefully catch the exception, and try again.

The code which fails is this part:

```
# go through each IP
for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
  set ip "10.$octet2.$i.x"

  puts "\n\n\n#### doing $ip...\n" ; flush stdout

  # log in to the IP
  spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l $user $ip
  expect {
    "continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" ; exp_continue }
    "login as: " { send "$user\r" ; exp_continue }
    "Password: " { send "$pwd\r" }
    "No route to host" { continue }
    timeout { continue }
    }

  # execute commands from file
  foreach c "$commands" { eval $c }

  }
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
Password:
Connection to 10.x.x.x closed by remote host.
Connection to 10.x.x.x closed.
send: spawn id exp11 not open
    while executing
"send "exit\r""
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $c "
    ("foreach" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"foreach c "$commands" { eval $c }"
    ("for" body line 18)
    invoked from within
"for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
  set ip "10.$octet2.$i.x"

  puts "\n\n\n#### doing $ip...\n" ; flush stdout

  # log in to the IP
  spa..."
    (file "./multido.exp" line 39)
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: what's the prompt after successful login?

Comment: I looks like this:
`rt-1.st-X.YYY`
Where X is a number and YYY is country code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception using the tcl command `catch` to surround the command that might error. You would extend your code's inner loop to resemble this:

```
set tryrun 1
while {$tryrun} {
    spawn ssh ...
    expect ...
    set tryrun 0
    foreach c "$commands" {
        if {[catch {eval $c} result]} {
          puts "failed: $result"
          set tryrun 1
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps a simpler solution would be to look for the pattern `"closed by remote host"` in your expect, and using this to repeat a similar loop.

Comment: Spot on !
Thanks a lot